# How can I force Excel to display scientific notation via EPPlus?

Tags: c#, excel, asp.net-core, epplus

Is there any way to control whether a number displays in scientific notation using the EPPlus library to generate an Excel file in C#?

```
worksheet.Cells[row, col].Value = someValue; //example value: 0.0000152691
worksheet.Cells[row, col].StyleName = RegularCenterAlign;
worksheet.Cells[row, col].Style.Numberformat.Format = "WHAT DO I PUT HERE???";
```

I tried "0.00e0" for the format and that causes excel to throw an error:

[image]

I didn't see it in the documentation but if you look in Excel at the formatting options, scientific notation is available, so you'd think EPPlus has a string code we could use for this.

What seems to be happening now is Excel is making its own determination about whether to format a given number in scientific notation. The same code inserted all of the numbers in the following screenshot. No format was specified but you can see that last one did not use scientific notation.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use:

```
ws.Cells["A1"].Style.Numberformat.Format = "0E+00";
```

You can add the number of decimals with something like:

```
ws.Cells["A1"].Style.Numberformat.Format = "0.0000E+00";
```

Don't forget that your value should be numeric. This value will be formatted:

```
ws.Cells["A1"].Value = 0.0000152691;
```

this one won't:

```
ws.Cells["A1"].Value = "0.0000152691";
```

Comment: Thank you! Where did you find this? I looked here: https://github.com/JanKallman/EPPlus/wiki/Formatting-and-styling

Comment: I created a excel file, put a cell with a number and format it with required format. Then uncompresed (.xlsx files are actually zip files), then opened file styles.xml. There I saw something like <numFmt numFmtId="166" formatCode="0.0000E+00"/> and said "Bingo" in spanish. XD

Comment: Haha, nice. I didn't realize I could just unzip an xlsx file. I just did it and opened my eyes to a whole new world. Thanks for the tip. Enjoy the so points.